# Implementing standard Dispose() pattern

Tags: c#

The standard way to implement `Dispose(bool disposing)` is as follows:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (resource != null)
            resource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why this can't be shorten to the following when using C# 6 and higher?

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
        resource?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Both your code blocks are one and the same.

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar after all....

Comment: "Is there any reason why this can't be shorten" You already gave the answer yourself: this works only for C#6 upwards.

Comment: Yes, it will not work on older versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, **when using C# 6 and higher** then there is no reason.

The second piece of code is syntactic sugar for the first so other than the *source* looking different, they're identical.

If you find articles that state that best practice is the first code, they're probably written way before C# 6 and the null conditional operator came along.

Comment: Thanks, it's one of those times when you want to double check before changing all of your code. Almost worth getting down voted for!

Comment: Why would you go "changing all of your code" ? It it isn't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: I wouldn't go about changing any of the code just because you learned this new syntax now. If, on the off chance, you're in that class/method and refactoring then sure, but as a "find and replace all instances of..." then no, definitely not. Don't change code that works just to change it. If you manage to forget just one question mark you've changed the behavior.

Comment: @bommelding I would only refactor if making other changes to the class

Comment: You wrote "_all_ of your code". But even when changing a class, why tweak it?  Same argument.

Comment: It turns out that using the null-conditional operator causes a false CA2213 from code analysis.